# use Joomla Subform field values in custom field from same module

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput, module-params, custom-field, subform

I have the basic xml file where in I call subforms into two tabs. Called Tab 1 and Tab 2. The content of this file is below.

mod_something.xml

```
<fieldset  name="tab1">
    <field name="storymaker" type="subform"
           formsource="/modules/mod_something/models/forms/storymaker.xml"
           min="1"
           max="9999999999"
           multiple="true"
           layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table"
           groupByFieldset="false"
           buttons=""
           label="MOD_SOMETHING_-STORYMAKER-_LABEL"
           description="MOD_SOMETHING_-STORYMAKER-_DESC" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset  name="tab2">
    <field name="characters" type="subform"
           formsource="/modules/mod_something/models/forms/characters.xml"
           min="1"
           max="9999999999"
           multiple="true"
           layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table"
           groupByFieldset="false"
           buttons=""
           label="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERS-_LABEL"
           description="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERS-_DESC" />
        </fieldset>
```

Now in the form that is loaded into tab1 I have this content.

storymaker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
  <field name="characterselection" label="" type="characterselection"/>
</form>
```

the form in tab 2 consists out of this:

characters.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
  <field
    name="character_name"
    type="text"
    default=""
    label="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERNAME-_LABEL"
    description="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERNAME-_DESC"
    size="10"
  />
</form>
```

In tab 1 I use a custom field this custom field is build up like this:

```
<?php

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$characters = $params->get('characters');
//$characters1 = $jinput->json->get('characters');
//$characters2 = $jinput->get('characters', null, null);
//$characters3 = $jinput->get->get('characters', NULL, NULL);
//$characters4 = $jinput->post->get('characters', NULL, NULL);
//$characters5 = $jinput->server->get('characters', NULL, NULL);
class JFormFieldCharacterSelection extends JFormField {

protected $type = 'characterselection';

public function getInput() {

  foreach ($characters as $character) {
    $character[] = $row->character_name;
  }
  // Merge any additional options in the XML definition.
  $options = array_merge(parent::getInput(), $character);
  return $options;
}
}
```

I have already tried everything I could think off but to no good. So here I am asking for your help.

## what do I want to achieve

A) In tab2 I have a list of names created via a repeatable subform so that it can be 10 names or a 1000.

B) In tab1 I have another repeatable subform wherein I want to display a dropdown generated from the names given in tab2.

C) Then I want to show these names on the frontend via the normal foreach used for the subforms.

```
$storymaker = $params->get('storymaker');
foreach ($storymaker as $sm) :
  echo $sm->characterselection . ' ';
  echo '<br><br>';
endforeach;
```

## what have I achieved so far

Sadly I only have achieved A. So I need help with B and I think that if that works C goes automatically alright but if not I might need help with that as well.

## what have I tried so far

I tried every single thing I could find on the internet about subforms and using parameters from a module inside a module. You can see parts of this left in the above code (commented).

## sorry for not being able to give short pinpointed code.

I had to put up all the files that are related to my problem otherwise I think no one would be able to understand what I am talking about. But sorry for the long text and code pieces.

## thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this doing it a bit different.

B is done via this code which grabs all the inputs and converts them to a select box. Then when the user makes a selection it copies that selection to a normal text form field. This is the field that you load to get the results for C. When the user hasn't selected anything it shows the word `character` in the select box.

```
        (function ($) {
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".selectArea").each(function(i) {
              $(this).addClass("selectBox" + (i+1));
            });
            var values = $("input[id^='jform_params__characters__characters'][id$='__character_name']").map( function(){return $(this).val(); }).get();
            var optionsPlaceholder = '###OPTIONS###';
            var optionPlaceholder = '###OPTION###';
            var select = '<select class="selectInput">' + optionsPlaceholder + '</select>';
            var option = '<option>' + optionPlaceholder + '</option>';
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                var currentOption = option.replace(optionPlaceholder, values[i]);
                options += currentOption;
            }
            var selectBox = select.replace(optionsPlaceholder, options);
            var $select = $(selectBox);
            $(".selectBox").html($select);
            $(".selectInput").each(function(i) {
              $(this).addClass("selectInput" + (i+1));
            });
            $("input[id^='jform_params__storymaker__storymaker'][id$='__characterselection_save']").each(function(i) {
              $(this).addClass("selectInputSave selectInputSave" + (i+1));
            });
          });

          $(document).on('change', '.selectInput', function() {
            var savevalue = (this.value);
            var selectClassRaw = $(this).attr("class").replace('selectInput selectInput', '');
            $('.selectInputSave' + selectClassRaw).val(savevalue);
          });

          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".selectInputSave").each(function() {
              var storedValue = (this.value);
              var storedClassRaw = $(this).attr("class").replace('selectInputSave selectInputSave', '');
              if ((this.value).length > 0) {
                $('.selectInput' + storedClassRaw).val(storedValue);
              } else {
                $('.selectInput' + storedClassRaw).prepend('<option>Character</option>').val('Character');
              }
            });
            $('.selectInputSave').parents('.control-group').addClass('hiddenSaveInput');
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

Keep in mind that the above code does not exactly work together with the previous codes as storymaker.xml is completely different

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <form>
    <field name="mode"
      type="radio"
      default="story"
      label="MOD_SOMETHING_-MODE-_LABEL"
      description="MOD_SOMETHING_-MODE-_DESC"
      class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
      >
      <option value="story">MOD_SOMETHING_-STORY-_OPTION</option>
      <option value="speech">MOD_SOMETHING_-SPEECH-_OPTION</option>
    </field>
    <field name="characterselectiongenerate" showon="mode:speech" label="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERSELECTION-_LABEL" description="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERSELECTION-_DESC" type="characterselectiongenerate"/>
    <field name="characterselection_save" type="text" default="" label="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERNAME-_LABEL" description="MOD_SOMETHING_-CHARACTERNAME-_DESC" size="10" />
  </form>
```