# How do I display the values from a subform

Tags: subform, repeatable-field

I have a sub form in my XML, which works fine in the back end, but I'm not sure of the best way to get the data out of the subform and display it.

Here's part of my original XML

```
        <field name= "repeatable_fields_map"
               description= "MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_DESC"
               type= "subform"
               label= "MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_LABEL"
               min= "1"
               max= "1000"
               required= "true"
               formsource= "/modules/mod_accreditations/xml/repeatablefieldsmap.xml"
               multiple= "true"
               buttons= "add,remove"
               layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable"
               groupByFieldset="false"/>
```

Here's my subform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
  <field name="accreditationImage"
         type="media"
         label="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_ACCREDITATION_IMAGE_LABEL"
         description="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_ACCREDITATION_IMAGE_DESC"/>
  <field name="accreditationText"
         type="text"
         label="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_ACCREDITATION_TEXT_LABEL"
         description="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_ACCREDITATION_TEXTE_DESC"/>
  <field name="link"
         type="url"
         label="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_LINK_LABEL"
         description="MOD_ACCREDITATIONS_REPEATABLE_FIELDS_MAP_LINK_DESC"/>
</form>
```

Here's how I outpur my `$params`

```
<?php echo "<pre>" . print_r($params, true) . "</pre>"; ?>
```

And here's what arrives

```
Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
(
    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            [repeatable_fields_map] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [repeatable_fields_map0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [accreditationImage] => images/accreditations/some-logo.jpg
                            [accreditationText] => SomeText
                            [link] => http://www.someurl.com
                        )

                )

            [moduleclass_sfx] => 
            [module_tag] => div
            [bootstrap_size] => 0
            [header_tag] => h3
            [header_class] => 
            [style] => 0
        )

    [initialized:protected] => 1
    [separator] => .
)
```

I know I need a foreach loop to access them, but I also know I can't use $params directly.

I've looked at other questions such as this: [Display values of JFormFieldRepeatable](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/display-values-of-jformfieldrepeatable) but it seems they use `attrib`s.  The thing that confuses me is that I don't see `attribs` in the XML.  Is this a special Joomla! function or am I being a noob?

Other  things I read which may help someone:
[How to get value from Sub Form](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17146/how-to-get-value-from-sub-form)
[use Joomla Subform field values in custom field from same module](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18189/use-joomla-subform-field-values-in-custom-field-from-same-module)
[How to save data from subform fieldtype in joomla 3.7 custom field](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/how-to-save-data-from-subform-fieldtype-in-joomla-3-7-custom-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$repeatable_fields_map = (array)$this->params->get('repeatable_fields_map');
foreach($repeatable_fields_map as $item) {
    $accreditationImage = $item->accreditationImage;
    $accreditationText = $item->accreditationText;
    $link = $item->link;
    // do stuff with these variables
}
```